# Can't access to the element on site in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to change pages like one by one, but can't access the element. http://prntscr.com/o0f4mx
I tried everything but didn't work. Please I need help.

```
XPath = //*[@id="___gcse_0"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[10]/div/div[2]
```

code:

```
tab2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="___gcse_0"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[10]/div/div[2]')
tab2.click()
```

And here is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/......", line 38,
>   in 
>       tab2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="___gcse_0"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[10]/div/div[2]')
>   File
>   "C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 978, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="___gcse_0"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[10]/div/div[2]"}

**Update - correct element** 
[image: Correct Element]

Comment: Sorry for showing the wrong element, here is right one: http://prntscr.com/o0f4mx

Comment: please approve the edits has been in pending they are necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WebdriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` and following xpath to handle dynamic element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='gsc-cursor']//div[@class='gsc-cursor-page'][contains(.,'2')]")))
element.click()
```

---

If above code doesn't click on the element then try JS executor to click on the element.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='gsc-cursor']//div[@class='gsc-cursor-page'][contains(.,'2')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```